# Can not delete the new created row using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue.I have one add(`+`) button in each row of the table when i clicked on that add button one new row is adding.Here i need when a new row will create one `-`(remove) button will stay with previous row and when user will click on remove button the corresponding row will be delete.I have done something but its not working.please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

link for the code and please help me.

Comment: Give correct plunker url.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: the plunker is empty

Comment: please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/DUo3uY3A6krm7pCtFQkZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try using Table deleteRow() Method

document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(index);

**Or Use**

Array splice() Method